# When I am trying to implement a vector inside a strcuture I am getting garbage values, How can I remove those garbage values

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
#pragma pack(1)
struct person{
    int age = 25;
    int salary = 20000;
    vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
};

#pragma pack()
int main() {
    person obj;
    person *p = new person(obj);
    int* ch = reinterpret_cast<int*>(p);
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
        std::cout<<"struct values"<<*ch++<<std::endl;
    }
    
    cout<<sizeof(struct person)<<endl;
    
}
```

Output:

```
struct values25
struct values20000
struct values-1272049920
struct values21971
struct values-1272049900
struct values21971
struct values-1272049900
struct values21971
struct values0
struct values0
struct values33
struct values0
struct values1
struct values2
struct values3
struct values4
struct values5
struct values0
struct values4113
struct values0
struct values1970435187
struct values1981838435
struct values1702194273
struct values808923507
struct values892547641
struct values168440116
struct values10
struct values0
struct values0
struct values0
struct values0
struct values0
32
```

Comment: why do you use `reinterpret_cast` ? And why did you expect to get any meaningful output ?

Comment: C++ has no reflection by default. Do not try to use `reinterpret_cast` to magically grab all member values. Use`p->a` to access the vector. Acutally you did luckily print the value 1~5 in `interpret_cast` but don't expect it would always work.

Comment: a `std::vector` is not an array of `int`, if thats what you did expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that you're **typecasting** a `person*` to an `int*` and then dereferencing that `int*` which leads to **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior. The program may just crash.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

In your code there is no need to use `new` or `reinterpret_cast` and you can use `->` to get access to the `vector` data member `a` as shown below:

```
struct person{
    int age = 25;
    int salary = 20000;
    std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
};

int main() {
    person obj;
    person *p = &obj; //or person *p = new person(obj)
    for(const auto& element: p->a)
    {
        std::cout<<element<<std::endl;
    }
    
   //no need to use delete here as we've not used new. But if you were to use new make sure you use delete
    
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/JmFvnnCeY)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>