# Is it possible to expose data of hard disk using pointer on a loop?

Tags: c++

I came to know about a method to expose the private data members using pointer.

This is the sample code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo{
private:
int x,y;

public:
foo(){
x=10;
y=11;
}
};

int main() {
int *ptr; 
foo f;

ptr = (int *)&f;

for(int i=0;i<2;i++){

    cout << *(ptr+i) << "  ";
}
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives output of : 10 11

So this is exposing the private datamember of value x and y.

Now I was wondering if it is possible to expose or revail the data of a complete hard disk using similar method? The data on hard disk is stored in the form of 0's and 1's and its easily possible to convert those 0's and 1's into readable format so if we do a loop from the starting of memory lets say memory address is 111111 so if I start a loop from 111111 to  the size of the hard disk then is that possible to expose all the data of hard disk?

This is an interesting topic for me and i was wondering if its possible to do some exploits like this? I am looking for depth answer on this.

Thank you very much for your time, I genuinely appreciate it!

Comment: The program has undefined behavior as you're typecasting a `foo*` to an `int*` and then dereferencing  that `int*` as also explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72431434/12002570)

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You could memory map the hard disk raw device and then access all the hard drive with a `char const*` pointer.  Such a program would need admin access, and may need to be run in single-user mode.  The device may have to be unmounted.

Comment: The private data members of a class, and the contents of a hard disk (private or not) have nothing in common. There's no reason that thinking a technique which works with one will also work with the other. One obvious issue is that hard disks do not have addresses in memory. You could memory map the hard disk to load it into memory, but that won't get around the security that is designed to prevent you reading the contents of a hard disk.